# Jacobians when integrating over symmetric and antisymmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus, jacobian

I'm interested in integrals over matrix elements. For integrals over the elements of a symmetric matrix $S$ or an antisymmetric $A$, how can I find the Jacobian of the transformations $S \rightarrow B^T S B$ or $A \rightarrow B^T A B$, where B is some real invertible matrix? Below shares my work and my guesses for what the Jacobians should be.

---

Here's a warmup that shows how I personally would find the Jacobian corresponding to a linear transformation of my matrix of interest.

Consider an integral over the $d$ by $d$ dimensional matrix $X$. That is, consider the integral $$\int_{\Gamma} f(X) dX .$$ $f(X)$ is schematic for a function of all the matrix elements. Here, $dX$ is schematic for $\prod_{i,j}^d dX_{ij}$. $\Gamma$ is some $d^2$-dimensional integration region.

If I were to consider a real, invertible transformation $U=BX$, one can quickly see by considering the columns of $X$ that $$\int_{\Gamma} f(X) dX = \int_{\Gamma} f(X) \prod_{j=1}^d \Big(\prod_{i=1}^d dX_{ij}\Big) = \int_{B\Gamma} f(B^{-1}X) \prod_{j=1}^d \frac{\prod_{i=1}^d dU_{ij}}{\det(B)} = \int_{B\Gamma} f(B^{-1}X)  \frac{\ dU}{\det(B)^d}.$$ That is, we have a Jacobian not of $\det(B)$ but of $\det(B)^d$.

One can check this makes sense by considering $B$ a constant $c$ times the identity matrix - then $\det(B) = c^d$, and $\det(B)^d = c^{d^2}$, which is exactly what one would get by scaling each of the $d^2$ elements of the matrix $X$ by $c$.

Thus, for $U=BX$, we have $dX \rightarrow \frac{dU}{\det(B)^d}$.

---

Similarly, we can see that $$\text{for }U=B^TXB\text{, we have }dX \rightarrow \frac{dU}{\det(B)^{2d}}.$$ This can be seen quickly by performing the transformation in two steps and considering the columns and rows of $X$.

However, what if our integration was over a *symmetric* matrix $S$? That is, consider the integral $\int_{\Delta} f(S)dS.$ Here, $dS$ is schematic for $\prod_{i\geq j}^d dS_{ij}$. Here, $\Delta$ is the integration region; counting the number of independent components of a symmetric matrix gives us that $\Delta$ must be a $\frac{1}{2}d(d+1)$-dimensional region.

Note that the transformation $U=B^TSB$ preserves the symmetry of $S$: $U$ is also symmetric. Then, by counting the number of independent components, $\frac{1}{2}d(d+1)$, I'd guess that

$$\text{for } B^TSB\text{, we have } dS \stackrel{?}{\rightarrow} \frac{dU}{\det(B)^{d+1}}.$$

Similarly, for an antisymmetric matrix $A$, we have that the transformation $U=B^T A B$ preserves the asymmetry; $U$ is also antisymmetric. Defining $dA = \prod_{i>j}^d dA_{ij}$, and noting $A$ has $\frac{1}{2}d(d-1)$ independent components, I'd guess that

$$\text{for } B^TAB\text{, we have } dA \stackrel{?}{\rightarrow} \frac{dU}{\det(B)^{d-1}}.$$

---

Are these guesses correct? How can I formally find the Jacobians of the transformations $U = B^T SB$ and $U=B^T AB$?

Answer (score 2):

The transformation $f(S) = B^T S B$ is a polynomial transformation, in the sense that every matrix entry on the right is a polynomial in the entries of $S$, with coefficients depending on $B$. In fact it is even a *linear* transformation, meaning that its Jacobian is itself. This is easy to see by picking some basepoint $P$ and making a small perturbation in the direction $A$:

$$ f(P + tA) = B^T P B + t B^T A B = f(P) + t B^T A B,$$

and hence $df_P(A) = B^T A B$ is the Jacobian at the point $P$.

The above working makes sense for any matrices $P$ and $A$. If you want to restrict to the linear subspace of symmetric or antisymmetric matrices, everything still works (because the tangent space to a linear subspace is itself, therefore all that changes in the above working is that both $P$ and $A$ are symmetric, or antisymmetric).

Comment: I was revisiting this question, and I realized that given that $B^T A B$ is the Jacobian, I'm no longer sure how to calculate the determinant of the Jacobian that ultimately enters when changing variables. For example, it's not clear to me from this answer that the determinant of the Jacobian that enters when changing variables with a given $B$ is different for general, symmetric, and antisymmetric matrices, giving different powers of the determinant of $B$. Could you please comment on that?